# Incorrect checksum for freed object - problem with allocation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to write a class in c++ that creates a dynamic array and I'm encountering this problem

```
malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7f9ff3c05aa8: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x2000000000000
```

I implemented three constructors (default, parametrized and copy) and I think this is the one causing problem because the code breaks here

```
CTable::CTable(string sName, int iTableLen)
{
    s_name = sName;
    cout<<"parametr: "<<s_name<<endl;
    c_table = new int[iTableLen];
    i_table_lenghth=iTableLen;
}
```

I also have to write a method changing the size of the array and returning true in case of the success and false in case of the failure. Maybe this method is causing the problem so this is how I implemented it.

```
bool CTable :: bSetNewSize(int iTableLen)
{
   int size;
   if(iTableLen < 0)
       return false;
   else if(iTableLen>=i_table_length)
       size = i_table_length;
   if(iTableLen < i_table_length)
       size = iTableLen;
   int *cTable;
   cTable = new int[iTableLen];
   for (int ii = 0; ii < size; ii++)
   {
       cTable[ii] = c_table[ii];
   }
   delete [] c_table;
   c_table = cTable;
   return true;
}
```

edit: The problem wasn't in any of those parts of the code. The method that was supposed to clone the object was causing the error. It happened because I allocated the object statically instead of dynamically. Here is the fixed method:

```
CTable* CTable::pcClone()
{
    CTable *obj_clone;
    obj_clone = new CTable(*this);
    return obj_clone;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `delete []cTable`?  Your variable names are similar so this feels like a typo.  If the code is correct, build with address sanitizer turned on or run your code through valgrind.

Comment: Your `bSetNewSize` function leaks memory and leaves `c_table` as a dangling pointer

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector` and dispense with all the problems?

Comment: Personally, I never use raw `new` or `delete` if at all possible. Can you use `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` or just `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: @StephenNewell I actually wanted to delete c_table which is the old array

Comment: Don't you miss `c_table = cTable;` at the end of `bSetNewSize()`?

Comment: Anything _wrong_ with `std::vector`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's an exercise and our professor wanted us to use a dynamic array

Comment: @NNZZ `std::vector` *is* a dynamic array 

Comment: @JesperJuhl okay my bad, I didn't know. Still, I don't think my professor would be happy if I don't do it according to his specification. Is there a way to fix what doesn't work in my code?

Comment: Did you mean to write `if(iTableLen >= 0) return false;`? Please post the *real* code. This is not it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you deleted `c_table` in `bSetNewSize()` and didn't set a new value to it, but used it in a later call. I Think you meant to put a `c_table = cTable;` to the end of `bSetNewSize()` function, as *500 - Internal Server Erro* commented.

Also it is faster if you take the `string` parameter as a `const string&` to the constructor.

Edit: are you sure abaut

```
if(iTableLen >= 0)
   return false;
```

This means that you actually resize only if `iTableLen` is negative.
Didn't you mean

```
if(iTableLen < 0)
   return false;
```